# MySQL select rows with two where conditions and count greater than 1 with same column ID

Tags: php, mysql, count, having-clause

In this example the result should be conversation_id 165337:

[image]

Here is the MySQL I have so far which does not work:

```
$value1 = $this->_getDb()->fetchCol("
SELECT conversation_id              
FROM xf_conversation_recipient
WHERE user_id = '4465'
AND user_id = '1'
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT conversation_id) > 1
");
```

Here is the answer and code which works:

```
$value1 = $this->_getDb()->fetchCol("
SELECT conversation_id, COUNT(*) c 
FROM xf_conversation_recipient
WHERE user_id IN ('4465','1') 
GROUP BY conversation_id HAVING c > 1
");
```

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE conversation_id = 165337`?

Comment: IN(1,2) GROUP BY..HAVING COUNT(*) = 2

Comment: I can't use "WHERE conversation_id = 165337" because that's the unknown result my query is looking for.

Comment: Try this then `SELECT conversation_id, COUNT(*) c FROM xf_conversation_recipient GROUP BY conversation_id HAVING c > 1;` @AndyBajka

Comment: Hi Fred, I tried your example but I get back all the conversation_id from the table. Not sure what "c" does, but it seams we are not limiting to user_id 4465 and 1.

Comment: Hi Fred, I added the "WHERE user_id IN ('4465','1')" to your example and now it works perfect. Thank you kindly for your help. I'll update the initial question to show the correct answer.

Comment: Hi Fred, could you explain what "c" does so we can understand how this work. Thank again.

Comment: It's just a placeholder/alias and you're welcome. Did you want me to convert my comment to an answer to close the question so it doesn't remain in the unanswered category? @AndyBajka

Comment: I made my comment as an answer below. We can close the question now and have placed what made it work as per your column query. @AndyBajka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this then:

```
SELECT conversation_id, COUNT(*) c 
FROM xf_conversation_recipient  
GROUP BY conversation_id HAVING c > 1;
```

and in your case:

```
$value1 = $this->_getDb()->fetchCol("
SELECT conversation_id, COUNT(*) c 
FROM xf_conversation_recipient
WHERE user_id IN ('4465','1') 
GROUP BY conversation_id HAVING c > 1
");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE user_id = '4465' AND user_id = '1'
```

correct

```
WHERE user_id  = '4465' OR user_id = '1'
```

Comment: Thank you, nigro.simone. This unfortunately returns the incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$value1 = $this->_getDb()->fetchCol("
SELECT conversation_id FROM xf_conversation_recipient WHERE user_id IN ('4465','1') HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
");
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, gptapravi. I tried this but $value1 is not the expected result. I suspect something with the HAVING COUNT DISTINCT is the problem.

Comment: Hi Strawberry, could you please show the exact code I would need to use GROUP BY.

Comment: changed the query after testing.

Comment: I just tried the latest suggestion, gptapravi. Sorry that isn't returning the correct result either. I keep getting back one result which is erroneous.